# Svnkit: getting the diffs between two commits revision remotely

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I want to get the Diffs between two revisions using SvnKit. I have looked at the documentation and found this method in `SVNRepository` class but it checks only the diff between a local copy and a remote one.

```
diff(SVNURL url, long targetRevision, long revision, java.lang.String target, boolean ignoreAncestry, SVNDepth depth, boolean getContents, ISVNReporterBaton reporter, ISVNEditor editor)
```

is there anyway to get the diff for a certain repository for a range of revisions  without downloading the repository ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're several APIs in SVNKit and SVNRepository-based API is the most low level, you need to have decent experience in working with Subversion internals to use it.

Instead it's better to use SvnOperationFactory-based API that works very similarly to "svn diff" command.

```
    final SvnOperationFactory svnOperationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
    try {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final SvnDiffGenerator diffGenerator = new SvnDiffGenerator();
        diffGenerator.setBasePath(new File(""));

        final SvnDiff diff = svnOperationFactory.createDiff();
        diff.setSources(SvnTarget.fromURL(url, SVNRevision.create(revision1)), url, SVNRevision.create(revision2)));
        diff.setDiffGenerator(diffGenerator);
        diff.setOutput(byteArrayOutputStream);
        diff.run();
    } finally {
        svnOperationFactory.dispose();
    }
```

It calls SVNRepository#diff does a lot of work except that. If you need more control on the output, you can implement your own ISvnDiffGenerator and pass it to the operation.